# What does all the formula and pictures mean?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, algorithm, bayesian-networks

https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-020-17419-7

I am a medical school graduate and I really want to learn AI/ML for computer-aided diagnosis.

I was building a symptom checker and I found the material. It clarifies the drawbacks of associative models which are performing differential diagnosis. And it suggests counterfactual(causal) approach to improve accuracy.

The thing is I couldn't understand what the formulas mean in the article, e.g.:

$$P(D \mid \mathcal{E}; \theta )$$

I really want to know what | and ; are doing here, what do they mean, etc.

I would really happy if someone can directly answer or just provide me some references to get general idea quickly.

Here comes the most tricy part...

[image]

Comment: This is a notation of a conditional probability, which means: The probability of $D$ given $\mathcal{E}$ with some parameters $\theta$. In other words, the likelihood of the event $D$ if event $\mathcal{E}$ happens. $\theta$ denotes parameters for the model (e.g., for neural network).

Comment: Thanks, @ArayKarjauv, I really want to know what the tau, sigma, and the division meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the provided article,

$$
\begin{equation} \tag{1}
P(D| {\mathcal{E}};\ \theta )
\end{equation} 
$$

is a probability of disease $D$ given findings $\mathcal{E}$, and a model $\theta$ that is used to estimate this probability.

> $D$ represents a disease or diseases, and findings $\mathcal{E}$ can
> include symptoms, tests outcomes and relevant medical history.

The Sheffer stroke symbol (vertical bar) `|` in the [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability) notation is read "given that", whereas the semicolon symbol `;` tells that we use a model (or parameters for the model) to calculate this probability. For instance, we can define this probability as $P(D| {\mathcal{E}};\ \theta ) = M_{\theta}(\mathcal{E})$, where $M$ can be a nueral network with parameters $\theta$ that takes $\mathcal{E}$ as input and returns the probability of $D$.

As we read the article further, we see that Equation 1 is nothing more than the [posterior probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterior_probability) from [Bayes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem):

$$
\begin{equation} \tag{2}
P(D| {\mathcal{E}};\ \theta )=\frac{P({\mathcal{E}}| D;\ \theta )P(D;\ \theta )}{P({\mathcal{E}};\ \theta )}.
\end{equation}
$$

where $P({\mathcal{E}}| D;\ \theta )$ is a likelihood of findings $\mathcal{E}$ given that we have the disease $D$, $P(D;\ \theta )$ is the prior probability of the disease $D$, and $P({\mathcal{E}};\ \theta )$ is a likelihood of findings $\mathcal{E}$.

As the article suggests, Theorem 2 is related to the [Noisy-OR model](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0888613X01000391?via%3Dihub), which itself is a large area of research. I encourage you to read the references provided in the article to learn more about approaches used by authors. If you have further questions regarding this theorem, I suggest you to open another question.